# Javascript - Updating global variables while in `requestAnimationFrame()`

Tags: global-variables, javascript

I am currently attempting to extract and update global variables from inside of an `requestAnimationFrame()` loop. The global variables inside of this scope does not update and am searching for a way to update the variables.

Here is a sample of my code (full source can be found at [**clmtrackr-clm_Video**](https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr/blob/dev/examples/clm_video.html)):

```
Var _myGlobal = "one";
function drawLoop() {
    requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
    overlayCC.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
    //psrElement.innerHTML = "score :" + ctrack.getScore().toFixed(4);
    if (ctrack.getCurrentPosition()) {
        ctrack.draw(overlay);
        _myGlobal = "two";
        document.getElementById('tester').innerHTML = _myGlobal; //prints "two"
    }
}
document.getElementById('tester').innerHTML = _myGlobal; //prints "one"
```

Note: I am trying to pass out the values while the video is still running (`animationframe`).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't assign to any variables in that code snippet, so what would you expect to update?

Comment: @Bergi, my apologies i did not include because the code didnt work, i have up=dated the code to better match my current problem/question.

Comment: The statement that prints `one` seems to be executed before `drawLoop` is called, where the other statement successfully updates the variable and prints `two`?

Comment: @Bergi yes, this seems to be the case, i just confirmed it. Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know what you *want* to do?

Comment: be able to update the global variable and use its value outside of the loop (or will that not work, and should I throw all of my code inside of the `animationloop`?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57719/discussion-between-the-doctor-and-bergi).

Comment: How are you calling the `animationloop`? When will it be finished? I guess you use `requestAnimationFrame`, which is *asynchronous*, so throwing everything that depends on the future values in the function is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, expecting that, but hoping there would have been another way. Cheers